# if the sum of even terms of $a_{n}$ equals $A$ and if the sum of odd terms of $a_{n}$ equals $B$, then the series $\sum{a_{n}}$ equals $A+B$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is the following implication true?

If the sum of even terms of $a_n$ equals $A$ and if the sum of odd terms of $a_n$ equals $B$, then $\sum a_n=A+B$

Comment: Is term $a_n$ even if $n$ is even, or is it even if $a_n$ is even?

Answer (score 1):

I preassume that in this context term $a_n$ is "even" if $n$ is "even" (and likewise for "odd").

Let $s_n:=\sum_{k=1}^na_k$.

Then evidently $s_n=e_n+o_n$ where $e_n$ is the sum of the $a_k$ with $k\leq n\wedge k\text{ is even}$ and $o_n$ is the sum of the $a_k$ with $k\leq n\wedge k\text{ is odd}$.

Then: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}(e_n+o_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}e_n+\lim_{n\to\infty}o_n=A+B$$where the third equality holds on base of the existence of both limits.

---

This also holds in the other interpretation that $a_n$ is "even" simply if $a_n$ is "even", et cetera. Only a slight adaption of the definitions of $e_n$ and $o_n$ is needed.